# Better way for Comparing List in c#

Tags: c#, list

I have two list say

```
List<string> names; and List<Student> stud;
```

Student Class has 3 properties

```
ID
Name
Section
```

Now i want to loop through `List<string>` and compare each item with Name property in `List<Student>` and want to perform operations if they are not equal

I tried looping through names and comparing each values to stud.

But i thought there must be some better way of doing this with `LINQ` or should i be using `YIELD`.

Thanks

Comment: They're parallel lists? (As in, same number in each?)

Answer (score 6):

It's not very clear from your description, but if you want "all students whose names aren't in the list" you can definitely use LINQ:

```
var studentsWithoutListedNames = stud.Where(s => !names.Contains(s.Name));
foreach (var student in studentsWithoutListedNames)
{
    // Whatever...
}
```

Comment: He says he wants to "loop" the names not the students if I understand it correctly. `names.Except(stud.Select(s => s.Name))`

Comment: @Magnus: Possibly. It's hard to say for sure. Hopefully the OP will come back to say either way.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is not what Jon describes but more to compare the list of names with the list of student names and find differences:

```
var invalidStudents = names.Zip(stud, (name, student) => new {name, student}).
                            Where(item => (item.name != item.student.Name));
if (invalidStudents.Any()) // Or foreach...
{
  ...
}
```

for example:

```
var names = new string[] { "John", "Mary" };
var stud = new Student[] { new Student(1, "John", "IT"), new Student(2, "Jack", "Math") };
var invalidStudents = names.Zip(stud, (name, student) => new {name, student}).
                            Where(item => (item.name != item.student.Name));
foreach (var item in invalidStudents)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.name);
}
```

Should write Mary

Answer (score 0):

Another good way of doing this would be:

```
var notOnList = students.Except(from student in students
                                join name in names on student.Name equals name
                                select student);
foreach(var student in notOnList)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Actually it has better time complexity than other proposed solution

Comment: It might, but you're sacrificing readability, imo, which is usually more important.

Comment: Also, do you have a source for a Linq join being better than O(n*m)?

Comment: @RoadieRich Left join with null check would probably be the best. Or Jon's solution if `names` is put into a `HashSet` first.

Comment: @RoadieRich just take a peek at Enumerable.GroupJoin method with reflector. It uses GroupJoinIterator which in turn uses Lookup for efficiency